# Guidance on AsTableServiceQuery with using Execute

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I noticed that when I call Execute() on a CloudTableQuery it does not make a request to Azure immediately. Take this code, for example:

```
var results = 
(from e in tableContext.CreateQuery<T>(tableName)
where e.PartitionKey == something
select e).AsTableServiceQuery().Execute();
```

The request to Azure is only made when I later consume the result:

```
foreach(var item in results) ...
```

If this is the case, then there is no point to having the explicit call to Execute in my code snippet. I am a bit confused by this behavior, and that leads me to ask: **What are the scenarios in which Execute() is required to be exposed publicly?**

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the source code for [TableServiceQuery.cs](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/microsoft-azure-api/Services/Storage/Lib/DotNetCommon/Table/DataServices/TableServiceQuery.cs) on GitHub, you will see the following.  Digging deeper, you can see Retry Policy, Server Timeout and Max Execution Time among other things are set by calling Execute()

```
    [DoesServiceRequest]
    public IEnumerable<TElement> Execute(TableRequestOptions requestOptions = null, OperationContext operationContext = null)
    {
        requestOptions = TableRequestOptions.ApplyDefaults(requestOptions, this.Context.ServiceClient);
        operationContext = operationContext ?? new OperationContext();
        long takeCount = TableUtilities.GetQueryTakeCount(this.Query, long.MaxValue);
        return
            General.LazyEnumerable(
                (continuationToken) =>
                this.ExecuteSegmentedCore((TableContinuationToken)continuationToken, requestOptions, operationContext),
                takeCount,
                operationContext);
    }
```

Comment: That looks like the new 2.0 code.  It is different for earlier versions.  I believe they both use LazyXXX however, which tells me it won't be invoked until you do something with it.  As such, I don't see a reason to use Execute - just use AsEnumerable() or ToArray() to run.

Answer (score 0):

After writing a few more queries, it seems like the `Execute()` is helpful for LINQ query composition. The table client does not provide support for some LINQ operators e.g. `Any()` and `Execute()` method can be used to continue composition on an `IEnumerable<T>`.

```
(from e in tableContext.CreateQuery<T>(tableName)
 where e.PartitionKey == "something"
 select e).AsTableServiceQuery(tableContext).Execute().Any()
```

Answer (score 0):

Linq queries are executed when you start using it, so for `IEnumerable`, your query is executed when you start to enumerate.

```
var query = (from e in tableContext.CreateQuery<T>(tableName)
    where e.PartitionKey == "something"
    select e).AsTableServiceQuery(tableContext).Execute();


foreach(var element in query)
{ 
    // the query has been executed
}
```

So you need to convert your query to ensure the execution (**.First(), .ToList()**):

```
// Retreive the fisrt element
var element = (from e in tableContext.CreateQuery<T>(tableName)
    where e.PartitionKey == "something"
    select e).AsTableServiceQuery(tableContext).Execute().First();

// Retreive all the elements
var elements = (from e in tableContext.CreateQuery<T>(tableName)
    where e.PartitionKey == "something"
    select e).AsTableServiceQuery(tableContext).Execute().ToList();
```